# Angular - how to fix Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to learn Angular but finding it very difficult. My boss thought it might help if I had some actual code to look at, so he's given me access to a project but i'm having difficulty getting it to run. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and have installed the latest node and npm. When I run

```
ng serve
```

I get the following error:

```
    Your global Angular CLI version (13.3.7) is greater than your local version (7.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path ".builders['app-shell']" should have required property 'class'.
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:215:42)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:69:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:59:18)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:92:26)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:28:21)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:55:26)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:67:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\eGDN Source\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:86:26)
```

I have tried to upgrade my local angular/cli by doing this

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

but it just gave me this error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@7.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"^7.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have found many solutions for similar issues on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but none seem to work for me. I know nothing about node, npm or angular, so i'm hoping someone can give me a simple step by step solution to get this working. Thanks

UPDATE:

Following the suggestion by cloned below, I ran

```
cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@8 update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8"
```

But, having selected y to proceed, I got this

```
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated read-package-tree@5.3.1: The functionality that this package provided is now in @npmcli/arborist
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @schematics/update@0.803.29: This was an internal-only Angular package up through Angular v11 which is no longer used or maintained. Upgrade Angular to v12+ to remove this dependency.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
    packageGroup metadata of package @angular/cli is malformed. Ignoring.
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "@w11k/angular-sticky-things" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^4.0.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=4.4.3 <4.7", would install "3.5.3").
                  Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.2.14").
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

Comment: How to update angular: https://update.angular.io go from one major version to the next one.